# Can't get Windows to boot from GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, bootloader

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 and am having some issues getting GRUB to work with me. Whenever I want to get to GRUB (to boot Ubuntu), I have to manually select it: 
[image: Selection of GRUB]. Then I can select Ubuntu from there. However, I want to make GRUB the default bootloader for my machine so it doesn't autoboot into Windows if I forget to press esc on boot. My GRUB screen looks like this: [image: GRUB]. When I select Windows, I get this screen: [image: Windows error]. If someone could help me figure out how to make grub my default bootloader and how to boot into windows from GRUB, I would love it! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop is using UEFI, which is needed for Windows 8 to secure boot.

To fix this, leave the boot option to "OS boot Manager" and boot a live-cd/usb and select try Ubuntu. When at the desktop start [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and click "Recommended repair". It will give a paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXXX/ url, note that down as we need it the repair doesn't work. Now reboot and you should see the GRUB menu.

Comment: Sounds good! I'll give this a go. But before I do, if something goes wrong, will anything happen to my HDD data or my ability to boot into Windows?

Comment: Also, by clicking on the link, I noticed it would be possible to do this without burning a live-cd/usb. Will this yield the same results or do I need a cd/usb? (I ask because I don't have a CD or USB available as of now).